# Disable bouncy scrolling in Cordova app for WP8

Tags: html, cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I've added

```
 this.CordovaView.DisableBouncyScrolling = true;
```

in my MainPage.xaml.cs (Cordova 3.5.0), to prevent the bouncing. But now all scrolling is disabled. (But I just wanted to disable the bouncing when scrolling outside the viewport area.)

When testing my HTML code inside the IE mobile browser everything works fine, but I would like to ship it as a "native" app.

Isn't `this.CordovaView.DisableBouncyScrolling` what I am looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer myself, by looking into `CordoveView.xaml.cs`:

```
this.bmHelper.ScrollDisabled = this.DisableBouncyScrolling;
```

Means `DisableBouncyScrolling` absolutely disables scrolling, which isn't what would expect from "disabling bouncy".

Comment: I am also facing this issue @miho, Can you explain your answer little bit more. What should I change?

Answer (score 0):

```
body{
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

This worked for me.